# Cannot assign to immutable indexed content while iterating

Tags: collections, struct, rust

I'm writing a library in Rust for a Java application and I'm trying to send data from the Java code to the Rust code. This data consists of structs called `Chunk`s which I construct on the Rust side. I'm also sending data to modify these structs, so they need to be mutable. I'm getting an error saying the `Chunk`s inside the `HashSet` are immutable, which shouldn't be the case.

```Rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct Chunk {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
    blocks: [[[i32; 16]; 16]; 16],
}

lazy_static! {
    // static mutable list (or at least it should be)
    static ref CHUNKS: Mutex<HashSet<Chunk>> = Mutex::new(HashSet::new());
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add_chunk(cx: i32, cy: i32, cz: i32, c_blocks: [[[i32; 16]; 16]; 16]) {
    // create Chunk and put it in the global list
    CHUNKS.lock().unwrap().insert(Chunk {x: cx, y: cy, z: cz, blocks: c_blocks});
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn update_block(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32, id: i32) {
    let cx: i32 = x / 16;
    let cy: i32 = y / 16;
    let cz: i32 = z / 16;

    let rx: i32 = if x > 0 { x % 16 } else { 16 + (x % 16) };
    let ry: i32 = if y > 0 { y % 16 } else { 16 + (y % 16) };
    let rz: i32 = if z > 0 { z % 16 } else { 16 + (z % 16) };

    for c in CHUNKS.lock().unwrap().iter() {
        if c.x == cx && c.y == cy && c.z == cz {

            // ERROR: cannot assign to immutable indexed content `c.blocks[..][..][..]`

            c.blocks[rx as usize][ry as usize][rz as usize] = id;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I should be using a `Vec` or `HashSet`, I went with the latter because it seemed the easiest.

Comment: Why don't you use a map from `(x, y, z)` to blocks?

Answer (score 4):

The original answer is incorrect - `HashSet` does not have `iter_mut()` method: changing elements of a hash table is unsafe, because their position is determined by their hash, so if a value changes, its hash also changes, but since it is modified in-place, it won't be positioned in the hash table correctly anymore, and will likely be lost.

Therefore, the most natural approach would be to use a `HashMap<(i32, i32, i32), Chunk>`, as suggested by @starblue:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref CHUNKS: Mutex<HashMap<(i32, i32, i32), Chunk>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add_chunk(cx: i32, cy: i32, cz: i32, c_blocks: [[[i32; 16]; 16]; 16]) {
    CHUNKS.lock().unwrap().insert((cx, cy, cz), Chunk {x: cx, y: cy, z: cz, blocks: c_blocks});
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn update_block(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32, id: i32) {
    let cx: i32 = x / 16;
    let cy: i32 = y / 16;
    let cz: i32 = z / 16;

    let guard = CHUNKS.lock().unwrap();
    if let Some(chunk) = guard.get_mut((cx, cy, cz)) {
        let rx: i32 = if x > 0 { x % 16 } else { 16 + (x % 16) };
        let ry: i32 = if y > 0 { y % 16 } else { 16 + (y % 16) };
        let rz: i32 = if z > 0 { z % 16 } else { 16 + (z % 16) };

        chunk.blocks[rx as usize][ry as usize][rz as usize] = id;
    }
}
```

Additionally, with a hash map you don't need to walk through the whole collection to get an item by its coordinates.

The original answer is below.

---

Your code is almost correct, you just need to use `iter_mut()` instead of `iter()`:

```
for c in CHUNKS.lock().unwrap().iter_mut()
```

or, alternatively:

```
for c in &mut *CHUNKS.lock().unwrap()
```

`iter()` returns an iterator which yields immutable references, so you can't modify anything through it. `iter_mut()`, on the other hand, returns an iterator yielding *mutable* references - exactly what you need.

Also, instead of directly calling `iter_mut()`, it is more idiomatic to rely on `IntoIterator` implementations for references to collections: for example, `&mut HashSet<T>` implements `IntoIterator` by calling `iter_mut()` on the set, so `for x in &mut hash_set` is equivalent to `for x in hash_set.iter_mut()`. Additional `*` here is required because `unwrap()` returns not just the contained value, but a `MutexGuard` which derefs to whatever the mutex contains.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `iter_mut()` in `std::sync::mutex::MutexGuard<'_, std::collections::hash::set::HashSet<Chunk>>`

Comment: Hmm, indeed you're right. I gues that's because changing hash set items is not safe - if you change them, their hash code will also likely change, and so it won't correspond to their position inside the hash set and the item would be lost. I guess using a map from (x, y, z), as suggested by starblue, would be more correct. I'll change my answer when I will be able to.